# How to detect when a UIWebView has completely finished loading in Swift

Tags: objective-c, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch

I need to reset the webview frame programmatically  ,when webview has completely finished loading .Delegate methods are added,but webViewDidFinishLoad is called multiple times for a single request.How can i check whether loading is complete or not in  webViewDidFinishLoad?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @priya.vr I update to check if its really finished

Comment: @cod3rite ,Updated the code ,issue is solved,Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use `UIWebViewDelegate`

There are two methods to detect on finish, one with success and another with error

```
extension YourViewController: UIWebViewDelegate {

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
        if webView.loading {
            // still loading
            return
        }

        print("finished")
        // finish and do something here
    }

    func webView(webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: NSError?) {
        print("didFailLoadWithError \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        // error happens
    }
}
```

dont forget to set to your `delegate` to `self` in `viewDidLoad` or in `didSet` (as recommended by @Jim)

```
myWebView.delegate = self
```

Comment: I find that it helps organise code better if you set up outlets using `didSet` instead of stuffing everything into `viewDidLoad()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var webView : UIWebView

    var url = NSURL(string: "http://google.com")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //load initial URL
        var req = NSURLRequest(URL : url)
        webView.loadRequest(req)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true

    }


    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView : UIWebView) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
        println("BB")
    }
}
```